# Running python in VSCode in M1 Mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, homebrew

I have installed python using homebrew and typing `python3 --version` in terminal it says "Python 3.9.13" which confirms that python is installed

But when I try to run a python program in VSCode in using Code Runner extension I get the following error in VS Code console
[image: Error Message]

Im thinking it has something to do with python being installed in wrong folder. Any help?

Comment: Have you installed the python extension in vscode?

Comment: @xpie Yes I have installed python extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed. I had to edit the `settings.json` file of the code runner extension to execute the Python program with the `python3` command instead of `python` like it was doing before (visible in the screenshot posted in question). Now it's running just fine.